# Netflix Falcor working together with Immutable.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js, falcor

I read about immutable.js, and the performance benefits it can give you in your react applications by implementing shouldComponentUpdate() that checks if the props or state has changed.

Also, I'd want to use Netflix Falcor in my application, is it possible to somehow use immutable.js collections inside falcor models?

Or is there a way to implement shouldComponentUpdate() with falcor models that will check for changes and will be fast (like with immutable.js)?

Comment: I was also thinking about this subject. I'm not sure it would be a new DataSource, Model or something else entirely, like a facade or proxy of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, i was thinking about the same thing for awhile. The thing is falcor is json graph data fetcher while immutablejs is about serializing/deserializing data for use in react components. It should found a common ground between the two or some sort of api to make them communicate while fetching data(falcor) and handling(immutablejs) data afterwards.

The best method I think so far to have the falcor model declare as api method which you pass to actions(flux) as promises, I use [alt](https://github.com/goatslacker/alt) as implementation, so in the api, webUtilAPI.js can look like this

```
'use strict';
 let Api = exports;
 import { Promise } from 'es6-promise';
 import { falcor } from 'falcor';

 Api.getFalcorData = () => {
     return new Promise((resolve) => {
        var model = new falcor.Model({
            source: new falcor.HttpDataSource('/model.json')
        });

        model.get("somedata").then((response) => {
            resolve(response.json.somedata)
        });
    })
}
```

afterwards in actions you can serialize it with immutablejs

```
'use strict';
import UUID        from 'node-uuid';
import Immutable   from 'immutable';
import alt from '../alt';
import webUtilAPI  from '../api/webUtilAPI';

class ActionCreators {

    constructor() {

        this.generateActions(
            'falcorToImmutable',
        );
    }
    getFalcor() {

        var that = this;

        return webUtilAPI.getFalcorData()
        .then(success(arr) => {
            var data = Immutable.fromJS({ id: UUID.v4(), arr })
            that.alt.getActions('ActionCreators').falcorToImmutable(data);
        });
    }
}
module.exports = ActionCreators;
```